# File not being recognized as such

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, nft

I have the following image file, but it is not being recognized as such.

```
image: {
fieldname: 'image',
originalname: 'certifcado.png',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/png',
destination: 'uploads/',
filename: '1e6df902f9997c26a917f42f52678628',
path: 'uploads/1e6df902f9997c26a917f42f52678628',
size: 127516
}
```

,

This format is properly recognized:

```
File {name: '340545_3.jpeg', lastModified: 1650928047655, lastModifiedDate: Mon Apr 25 2022 18:07:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 13548, …}
lastModified: 1650928047655
lastModifiedDate: Mon Apr 25 2022 18:07:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) {}
name: "340545_3.jpeg"
size: 13548
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

This is the output of [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)   middleware for express js. I am using it to upload a file, but nft.storage's "store" function shows the following error:

```
TypeError: property `image` must be a Blob or File object
```

This is my function:

```
app.post('/api', upload.single('image'), async function(req, res) {
  
  const file = new File(req.file);
  console.log(file instanceof File);
  const song = {
    image: file,
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,    
    }
  }
```

As you may see, I double check that the object is indeed a file, yet nft,storage wont process it as such. This is my code:

```
const {ethers} = require('ethers');
const {NFTStorage} = require('nft.storage');
const express = require('express');
const File = require("file-class");
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());

async function storeNFT(song) {
  const client = new NFTStorage({ token: process.env.token })
  const metadata = await client.store(song)
  console.log('NFT data stored!')
  console.log('Metadata URI: ', metadata.url)
}

app.post('/api', upload.single('image'), async function(req, res) {
   const image = req.file;
  const song = {
    image: image,
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
  }
  
   const metadata = storeNFT(song);
  }),

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.warn(`The app is listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
```

edit: Further clarification

Comment: It's unlikely people can help without seeing the relevant code and a more complete description of the problem and include a lot more of the context in your question for what you're trying to do.   For example what does "it won't recognize it as a file" mean?  What is "it"?  What are you expecting it to do?  What does it do instead?

Comment: thank you, I have added extra information

Comment: You refer to issues with `nft.storage.store()` function, but you don't show any code that shows any nft storage operations or show the code responsible for the error you mention.  Again, it's hard for us to follow what you're doing or where/why the error is occurring when you don't include enough of the relevant code.  Perhaps worth reviewing [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the stackoverflow help center.

Comment: my apologies again, updated

Comment: So, the error message you get is "TypeError: property `image` must be a Blob or File object", but you are passing `req.file` as your image which is probably a filename in the `uploads` folder, right?  So, you're not passing what `storeNFT()` wants.

Comment: req.file is the object received on the api POST call, i have confirmed "image instance of File > TRUE", so I am passing the whole file to the storeNFT method

Comment: @Msantamaria were you able to resolve this? I'm experiencing a similar issue.